# How to remove multiple HTML files in batch

Tags: ubuntu, filenames, rm, desktop-environment

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Gnome version 3.18.2 My desktop filled with multiple html pages (GHex editor output).

```
binary00000000.html 
binary00000001.html
binary00000002.html
... 
binary00043310.html
```

How to remove these HTML files from desktop in batch?

Comment: `rm $HOME/Desktop/*.html`

Comment: ... or perhaps restrict the scope slightly: `rm $HOME/Desktop/binary*.html` if you don't want to delete *ALL* html files.

Comment: I want remove **only** above html files based on mask. There is other html files too, that should not be removed.

Comment: How do you distinguish the ones you want to keep from the ones you want to remove?

Comment: Based on mask: so @NickD comment was helpful. I removed them use `rm binary*.html`.

Comment: What is a mask?  Based on context it seems like you mean to say prefix?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say based on _prefix_, it would be correct.